# Programa imprime a próxima letra do alfabeto em vez de do próximo char no ponteiro

Tags: c, ponteiro, console, printf

Meu programa está imprimindo a letra `P` ao invés do `i`, gostaria de entender o problema por trás disso e  o que está errado no meu código. Se eu botasse a letra `A` ao invés do `O`, o programa iria imprimir a letra `B`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (){
    char *p = {'O', 'i'};
    p++;
    printf("%c\n", p);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem dois erros neste código. Um dele é que não alocou memória para colocar o conteúdo, então vai acessar lixo na memória.

E o outro é que não está acessando o conteúdo apontado por `p` e sim o valor de `p`, então precisa *dereferenciar* o valor. Se quer acessar o valor de `p` então tem que usar outro formatador, mas ainda não dará o que deseja:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int main () {
    char *p = malloc(2);
    p[0] = 'O';
    p[1] = 'i';
    p++;
    printf("%c\n", *p);
    printf("%p\n", p);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3jyin5). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/buenpgfn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/Dereference2.c).

Comment: Se eu coloco `1` no `malloc ()` o código continua funcionando normalmente e mostra o `i`, o certo não seria alocar 1 byte para cada índice? Sendo assim `malloc (2)` pode alocar o `p[0]` e `p[1]`. Grato pela resposta desde já.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdAbK.jpg. O certo é alocar um byte para cada índice, por isso foi alocado 2.

Answer (score 1):

Como você declarou apenas um ponteiro `*p` do tipo char. O progama está armazenando apenas a primeira posição, ou seja a letra 'O'. Quando incrementa `p++`, voce não está saltando para o endereço de memoria seguinte, está apenas incrementando o valor 79 que corresponde ao codigo ASCII  da letra 'O' na tabela ascii. O mesmo ocorre com o caractere 'B'. Então quando dar um `printf("%c",p)` é impresso na tela a letra correspondente ao codigo ascii [veja mais](https://web.fe.up.pt/%7Eee96100/projecto/Tabela%20ascii.htm)

Para imprimir o codigo ascii em vez da letra é so trocar o `%c` por `%d`, assim `printf("%d", p)`. Na tabela as os codigos das letras estao organizados em sequencia por isso é impresso a letra seguinte